# DateTime in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to get datetime(ex: 2013-09-20 21:32:49.000) from SQL and display only date(ex: 2013-09-20) in SSRS.

Could anyone let me know the syntax for doing this.
I tried below syntax but no luck

```
=First(Fields!Start_date.Value, "Database_Name")
```

Answer (score 7):

**Method 1:**
You can format date in textbox properties. Right click on textbox and go to textbox properties.

[image]

**Method 2:**
Set the expression something like

`=FormatDateTime(Fields!Start_date.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)`

Comment: How do I add the database name for the above mentioned syntax?

Comment: In method 1 you will keep your expression as it is. In second method the expression would be `FormatDateTime(First(Fields!Start_date.Value, "Database_Name"), DateFormat.ShortDate)`